# Collection of ToggleButton in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I am trying to implement a Control Panel that will contain few button in it (Regular buttons and Toggle buttons).

The problem is to handle the "IsChecked" property of the ToggleButton.
I want it to remain in sync with the original property all the time.

- I implemented ObservableCollection of IControl interface.
- ToggleButtonVm and ButtonVm will implement IControl interface.
- I want to initialize the ObservableCollection from MainViewModel
- I want to Bind the IsChecked property of the ToggleButton with the IsMarked property in the MainViewModel.

for example:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<IControl> ControlPanelItems { get;set; }
    private bool _isMarked;

    public bool IsMarked
    {
        get { return _isMarked; }
        set
        {
            _isMarked= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public unsafe MainViewModel()
    {
        ControlPanelItems = new ObservableCollection<IControl>() { new ToggleButtonVm(IsMarkedCallback, IsMarked) };
    }

    public void IsMarkedCallback()
    {
        IsMarked = !IsMarked;
    }
}

public class ToggleButtonVm : ViewModelBase, IControl
{
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; }
    }


    public ToggleButtonVm(Action isMarkedCallback, bool isMarked)
    {
        IsChecked = isMarked;
        Command = new RelayCommand(isHazingCallback);
    }
}

public interface IControl
{
}
```

This is the xaml code

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:ToggleButtonVm}">
      <ToggleButton Command="{Binding Command}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"></ToggleButton>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid >
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ControlPanelItems}"></ListBox>
  </Grid>
```

How can i make the togglebuttons created from the datatemplate bind correctly to the property is mainviewmodel with proper mvvm.

Thanks

Comment: *How can i make the togglebuttons created from the datatemplate bind correctly to the property in mainviewmodel with proper mvvm*... you can't data bind multiple `ToggleButton.IsChecked` properties to a single `IsMarked` property in your main view model unless you want all of them to be selected at once. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: Give each item an IsChecked property in its ViewModel

Comment: in addition to Sheridan's comment, you will need to use `OnpropertyChanged` of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but your example shows that you want to have one property that is bound to all button which means if you set IsMarked to true then all buttons property will be set to true. The easiest way is to set in datatemplate:
 <ToggleButton Command="{Binding Command}" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName="YourRootName",Path=DataContext.IsMarked}"></ToggleButton>
And name your root "YourRootName" or using AncestorType Parent. Mode should be set to TwoWay to stay synchronized. If you want to manipulate it in ViewModel then remember about INotifyPropertyChanged.